# How can i get an Integer out of an JBCD Resultset?

Tags: java, mysql

**Hello!**

I'm new in handling MySQL databases in Java.
So, my problem is, I want to get an Integer out of my Database.

So, that's my method to get an ResultSet:

```
    public static ResultSet getResult(String syntax) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(syntax);
        return statement.executeQuery();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is my how I call the method above:

```
            ResultSet rs = MySQL.getResult("SELECT playedtime FROM ffa_playerdata WHERE UUID='"
                + p.getUniqueId().toString() + "'");
```

So, how can I make an Integer out of that?
Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getInt`

```
if(resultSet.next()){
 Integer result = resultSet.getInt("playedtime");
}
```

And btw, use [PreparedStatment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of string concatenation for constructing the query, it is safer and cleaner.

Comment: @LeLyfa I don't have enough info to know why it's not working for, but it should work